# Avoid Ubuntu kernel Upgrade

Tags: kernel

So I have marked linux-image-generic and linux-headers-generic on hold so I can run my desktop on old kernel even after an upgrade. But I see that if I am doing dist-upgrade it is upgrading the kernel as well even though it is on hold. Please suggest how can I disable kernel upgrades completely and how can I start my desktop  on previous kernel? Currently I am on 16.04.1 4.4.0-116.

Thanks,
Zain

Comment: What's the reason you are running `dist-upgrade` on an Ubuntu system instead of a more appropriate command like plain old `upgrade`?

Comment: Since dist-upgrade removes and solves dependencies issue more smartly than upgrade.

Comment: is there a way I can completely disable kernel upgrade?

Comment: Freeze linux-generic as well.

Comment: How should I do that @Thomas?

Comment: So I did this by configuring file under preference.d. Can anyone help me in giving a link or something to this so I can educate myself more about this?